# django rest: AssertionError at /api/v1/users/1/ 'UserDetail' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to follow a tutorial from the book 'Django for APIs', this tutorial consists on doing a blog project API with django rest framework.

I cant get to work the UserDetail view at url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/int:pk/'
it raises the following error ,although queryset is defined in the UserDetail class in views.py:

**AssertionError at /api/v1/users/1/**

**'UserDetail' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.**

here is the code:

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFjce.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXUQn.png)

[serializers.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z5Zw.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJCoh.png)

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserList, UserDetail, PostList, PostDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/',UserList.as_view()),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', UserDetail.as_view()),
    path('',PostList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetail.as_view()),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Post
from .permissions import IsAuthorOrReadOnly
from .serializers import PostSerializer, UserSerializer

# Create your views here.

class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset_= get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

serializers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','author','title','body','created_at',)
        model = Post

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields  = ('id','username',)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `UserDetail`, it should `queryset` not `queryset_`

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

Comment: thank you so much! I spent hours searching for syntax errors, and didnt realize that! thank you